# Google Drive uploading a file, and reading a file

Tags: java, google-drive-api

.Net guy working on a java app

I am uploading using the following example as my starting point ( I have this working).  This shows using FileContent needing a java.io.File which does not contain the actual file only a pointer to the actual file.

We are uploading from a web site and attempting to insert into the drive, I would prefer to do this using a memory Stream like the .Net example.  I cannot see that in looking at the FileContent class.  So my questing is: **Is there a way to insert a file in Google drive that is in memory and not first on the hard drive?**

```
private static File insertFile(Drive service, String title, String description,
  String parentId, String mimeType, String filename) {
// File's metadata.
File body = new File();
body.setTitle(title);
body.setDescription(description);
body.setMimeType(mimeType);

// Set the parent folder.
if (parentId != null && parentId.length() > 0) {
  body.setParents(
      Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(parentId)));
}

// File's content.
java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(filename);
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(mimeType, fileContent);
try {
  File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();

  // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID.
  // System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());

  return file;
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
  return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the AbstractInputStream build your own FileContent

```
package com;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent;
import com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions;

public class FileContent extends AbstractInputStreamContent {

private InputStream inputStream = null;
private long  inputLength = 0;

public FileContent(String type, InputStream pInputStream) throws IOException {
    super(type);
    this.inputStream = Preconditions.checkNotNull(pInputStream);        
    this.inputLength = this.inputStream.available();
}

public long getLength() throws IOException {
    return this.inputLength;
}

public boolean retrySupported() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    return this.inputStream;
}
}
```